# See you on 7th October or I am seeing you on 7th October

Tags: present-progressive

I am about to say goodbye to a friend that I know that I’m going to meet again on the 7th of October.

Before leaving should I say “See you on the 7th of October", "I will see you on the 7th of October” or “I am seeing you on the 7th of October”? My doubt is, if it is a fixed plan, why not use the present continuous form, *I am seeing you..*?

And in case I am looking at my schedule and someone asks me when I am going to see someone (for example my mother), can I say, "I am seeing my mother on the 7th of October"?

Comment: You’re saying “See you later.” except you’re replacing “later” with a date.  Also, I don’t know anyone who says “seventh October” they say “October seventh”.  To put the day first it’d be “... on the seventh of October”

Comment: If speaking in American English, you can just write, "See you October 7."  If speaking in British English, you can just write, "See you 7 October."  How people read dates aloud is often different than exactly how the date is written.

Comment: @Nancy As a speaker of British English I would never use a cardinal number for a date unless I was writing it with slashes or other punctuation (7/10/2019 for example). If I was writing it in the form you suggest I would always use the ordinal form for the day number (7th October) but would insert 'on' and the the definite article before the day when speaking giving "I'll see you on the 7th of October". I might also say "I'll see you on October the 7th" having written it as "I'll see you on October 7th" but I might miss out the definite article in that case, although not the 'on'.

Comment: In the US, the most common things for these specific situations would be "See you on October 7th" and "I'll see her on October 7th."

Comment: Presumably you are not telling your friend what the arrangement is -  'I am seeing you on...' - as they already know. For a friendly salutation on parting, either of the others will be OK.

Answer (score 2):

Since you will be seeing your friend on the 7th of October, you could say

> See you ... / I will see you ... / Can't wait to see you ...
>
> - soon.
> - next month.
> - on the 7th of October.
> - in a couple of a weeks.
> - in a few weeks.

---

As for someone asking you when you are going to see someone, you could say

> I will be seeing my mother *on the the 7th of October.*

You can replace the  *on the 7th of October* with any of the five options above.

Comment: It might be suggested that the last listed option should be " in a few weeks" since "couple" implies multiples of two.